# json ajax jquery returns [object object] wrong output

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, each

I need some help over here.
I am coding simple inventory. 
I've been trying to fix this whole night but with no success.
I have problem with output the json data in html table in second $.each with ajax call. What I found annoying no matter what I do, even using JSON.stringify it continues to returns Object object in html, but no problem with console.log.

The code:

```
$('.filterProduct').on('change', function(event) {

            $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'filter_products', 
            data: {
                'brand_id' : $('#brand_id').val(),
                'type_id' : $('#type_id').val()   
                },


            success: function(data){ 


                $('tbody').empty();
                var i=1;
                $.each(data, function(index, product) {
                    $('tbody').show('fast');

                    $('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+i+++'</td><td>'+product.sku+'</td><td>'+product.product_name+'</td><td>'+product.description+'</td><td>'+product.price+'</td><td id="sizes">'+
                            $.each(product.sizes, function(ind, val) {
                                sizeName = val.size_name;
                                sizeQty = val.quantity_per_size;
                                var tdSizes = $('td#sizes');

                                console.log(val.size_name, val.quantity_per_size);
                                console.log(tdSizes.append(sizeName, sizeQty));
                        })

                        +'</td><td>'+product.id+'</td><td>'+product.feature_image+'</td><td>'+product.status_id+'</td><td>'+'Reserve'+'</td>');
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

Here it is the json in console.
[json data in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTICa.png)

What is interesting is that in first 3 iterations it returns prevobject but next 3 the correct selector. I tried selecting the needed  tag with nth-of-type and also targeting with class and id, in all situations it returns the same wrong results. But console.log shows correct values, but in  tag wrong.
[the returning of data shown in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcHnc.png)

Here it is the output in HTML (I can't post more than 2 images), as you can see it shows the values after 3th iteration. I have no explanation for that. But if I try to put the output outside the  (even in  it throws the wrong output) tag, for example in  it shows the correct values.

html shown in table (I can show it in image, so I will paste it here):

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]L5XL17L9

[object Object],[object Object]L9

[object Object]

as you may have noticed, last  does not return any values..

Hope you will help me, if you need more info, just write me.
Thanks

Comment: This depends on the response object you are receiving. Looks like you are receiving an object where you are expecting a string.

Comment: You are concatenating the return value of the inner `$.each()` function into the middle of the string of HTML that you are creating, and the return value is an object so it gets converted to the string `"[object Object]"`. (Also, trying to use `'td#sizes'` isn't going to work, because you're creating elements with duplicate IDs, which is invalid HTML and selecting by ID will only find the first one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit messy. Take the second `each` out of the html creation part.

Create a variable `sizes_html` and save the `each` result in it. Then you add the `sizes_html` as variable... I've never seen a an `$.each` in the middle of sting concatenation.

Here's what I mean:

```js
var product = {sizes:[ 
{size_name:"XS", quantity_per_size: 5},
{size_name:"S", quantity_per_size: 10},
{size_name:"M", quantity_per_size: 15},
{size_name:"L", quantity_per_size: 20},
{size_name:"XL", quantity_per_size: 25}
]};


var sizes_html = "";

$.each(product.sizes, function(ind, val) {
  sizeName = val.size_name;
  sizeQty = val.quantity_per_size;
  sizes_html += sizeName + " (" + sizeQty + ") |";
});


$('tbody').append('<tr><td>123</td><td>'+product.sku+'</td><td>'+product.product_name+'</td><td>'+product.description+'</td><td>'+product.price+'</td><td id="sizes">'+sizes_html+'</td><td>'+product.id+'</td><td>'+product.feature_image+'</td><td>'+product.status_id+'</td><td>'+'Reserve'+'</td>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Much cleaner. Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Miro :)
Can't vote, but save my night :)